# MOQ: Cant cast Moq.Mock to Interface in VB.Net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, moq

I am writing a simple unit test to check if the proper view name is being returned by an ActionResult in VB.Net MVC 1.  The controller requires a service and I am trying to Mock the service but keep getting this error.

```
Unable to cast object of type 'Moq.Mock`1[SRE.Web.Mvc.INotificationService]' to type 'SRE.Web.Mvc.INotificationService'.
```

As I said, the simple and I'm not sure where to go from here.

Here is the test.

```
<Test()> _
    Public Sub Index_Properly_Validates_Email_Address()
        'Arrange
        Dim fakeNotifcationService As New Mock(Of INotificationService)(MockBehavior.Strict)
        Dim controller As New CustomerServiceController(fakeNotifcationService)
        Dim result As ViewResult


        'Act
        result = controller.Feedback("fake@fake.com", "fakesubject", "fakemessage")
        'Assert
        Assert.AreEqual("thankyou", result.ViewName)

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The type `Mock(Of INotificationService)` is not convertible to `INotificationServec` hence you are getting this error.  To get to the actual mock'd object you need to use the `Object` property.

```
Dim controller As New CustomerServiceController(fakeNotifcationService.Object)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need `fakeNotifcationService.Object`.